# getting the changes in a unstaged file

Tags: git, command-line, git-diff, git-status

When I run this command:

```
$ git status
```

Here is the result:

```
/* red color - I haven't added them yet */
modified:   inaccessible/dbh_conn.php
modified:   myweb/.idea/workspace.xml
modified:   myweb/application/search.php
```

Now I need to see the changes in `search.php` file. How can I see that? I guess I should use `$ git diff` command. But apparently it has a limited result and the changes in `workspace.xml` are too much, so I cannot see the changes in other files after that.

Anyway, how can I say to git, show me **only** the changes in a specific file?

Comment: _"I cannot see the changes in other files after that."_ - what do you mean? `git diff` without arguments will show changes in all the files. It shows the diff in a pager, press page down/down arrow to scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `git diff myweb/application/search.php` command.

Answer (score 0):

git diff myweb/application/search.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use git diff myweb/application/search.php

Additionally using git ignore command you can put myweb/.idea/workspace.xml (if the changes are irrelevant) file to ignore list which doesnt show its changes.